# What's the meaning of 「そのさま」?

Tags: expressions, word-usage

Recently, I looked up the definition of 「流暢{りゅうちょう}」 in a monolinguistic Japanese dictionary, and the definition is as follows:

> 言葉が滑らかに出てよどみないこと。また、そのさま。

What is the meaning of そのさま in this situation? I've never seen this usage before, and I can't seem to find any information on it on Google.

Comment: "Or, the appearance of such."

Comment: 「言葉が滑らかに出てよどみない**こと**。」 indicates that the word 流暢 is a noun, and 「また、そのさま。」(≒その[様子]{ようす}), i.e. 「また、言葉が滑らかに出てよどみない**さま**。」, indicates that it can also be used as an adjective (流暢な/流暢だ/流暢に...)